# Como adequar meus dados para usar no Theano?

Tags: python

Estou seguindo o tutorial do livro-blog http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/ e gostaria de aplicar os códigos no meu próprio dataset de imagens.

Como não sei muito de python, fiz algumas pesquisar e descobri que precisava colocar os meus dados em um array multidimensional como no código abaixo:

```
import pickle
import Image
import numpy as np
def generateDataset(filesDir):
   x = np.asarray([np.asarray(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filesDir]) #gera array com todas images
   with open('dataset.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
       pickle.dump( x, handle, protocol=2) #salva como .pkl
```

Porém, quando carreguei o arquivo utilizando cPickle e enviei como parâmetro do método usado nos exemplos, recebo o erro:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

O que me faz acreditar que esse não seja o modo correto de adaptar meus dados aos utilizados no código. 
Alguém sabe como faço para adequar meus dados ao usado nesse exemplo, ou como faço para utilizar meu próprio dataset no Theano?

Algumas informações extras: O dataset utilizado no livro é o mnist e minhas imagens são 320x320 em nível de cinza.

Obs: O github com os códigos utilizados estão no primeiro link

Obrigado desde já.